# How to modify Django admin filter's title

Tags: django, django-admin, django-filter

I have a filter (one of the defaults and not custom)

Is it possible just to change the title of filter, without write a full new custom filter ?

Because the only customization I need from the filter is its title. THere should be a way to do that without rewriting the whole filter and lookups.

Comment: No obvious way, writing a custom filter is the easiest way. Otherwise you need to override `ChangeList.get_filters` or modify the title on-fly through Javascript.

Comment: Modifying the JS would be very non pythonic. Impossible to traceback and bad while maintenance phase.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You *will* need to have a custom filter class, but you can actually implement a custom filter class factory that you can use everywhere you just need a filter with a custom title:

```
from django.contrib import admin

def custom_titled_filter(title):
    class Wrapper(admin.FieldListFilter):
        def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
            instance = admin.FieldListFilter.create(*args, **kwargs)
            instance.title = title
            return instance
    return Wrapper
```

After that in your `ModelAdmin` class:

```
list_filter = (
    ('fieldname', custom_titled_filter('My Custom Title')),
    'plain_field',
    ...
)
```

(Note how the custom filter is not just a field name, but a tuple of `(field_name, CustomFilterClass)`, you're just getting your `CustomFilterClass` from your `custom_titled_filter()` factory)

Comment: Note you'll need to inherit from `admin.RelatedFieldListFilter` if you want to filter on a foreign key value.

Comment: @lanzz: Closing `)` is missing: `('fieldname', custom_titled_filter('My Custom Title')),`

Comment: I would recommend custom_title_filter(title, Klass)

Comment: Also, create() is garbage. You just need Klass(*args, **kwargs), at least as of 1.10

Answer (score 66):

if you define labels on your fields in your model, you should see the change on filter options: Like,

```
is_staff = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="My Best Staff's", default=False)
```

Here "My Best Staff's" is filter Label.

Comment: if attributing is spanning across long extended relation this seems to not working for me
eg.  area__forest__trees__id